# Pass by reference in C: how is result variable initialized?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I am new to C, and I have to make a mini calculator program (this is homework, but I'm not looking for the answer, just a little more understanding). Basically, one function must look like this:

```
int add(double d, double dd, double *result);
```

It will return a 0 if there are no errors, and -1 if an error occurred (in the case of addition, there wouldn't be many errors - but division for example, divide by 0 would be an error).

A user has to input two numbers into the terminal, those numbers then get used as the parameter values in the add method. What I don't understand is what is result initially when the method is called? Is it just null? And why would I want to return 0 or -1 and not result instead? For example:

```
double result;
returnValue = add(2.0, 5.0, &result);
```

Obviously I'll get 7 as the result, but how will I print that out without returning the result? returnValue is 0, so I know there were no errors, so now I need to print result.

Comment: Do not use/print `result` unless the `returnValue` is successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C doesn't have pass by reference.  You can pass in a pointer, which is what you're doing here, but C only has pass by value.

Now to your actual questions:

> What I don't understand is what is result initially when the method is called? Is it just null?

No, the value of `result` is undefined before the `add` function is called.  You have *no guarantees whatsoever* if you try to use the value of `result` before assigning to it, either by assigning to it in the function where it's declared or by assigning to it in `add` with code like `*result = d + dd`.

For that matter, a double can never be `null`.  Null is a possible pointer value, not a possible floating-point number.

> And why would I want to return 0 or -1 and not result instead?

If you were to return `result` directly, you'd have to have some kind of distinguished "calculation failed" return value, which is kind of messy and leaves the caller to check the result before using it.  This way forces the caller of `add` to notice that there is status code as the return value, and if the caller wants to ignore it then they can (although you shouldn't ignore status codes).

> Obviously I'll get 7 as the result, but how will I print that out without returning the result?

Ed Heal is right to suggest `printf`.  If you're using Linux or Mac OS X, though, I'd also recommend running `man printf` from the terminal - it's often more convenient than opening a web browser.

Comment: As you said C does not have references - but a pointer is a reference in the C standard. You answer will not compile with a C compiler

Comment: Yes, I apologize, that was a typing error on my part. I have now fixed it.

Comment: @AdrianCornish "a pointer is a reference" is not true.  Eric Lippert wrote [a nice blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/07/references-and-pointers-part-one.aspx) about the difference.  The post is C#-specific, but many of the same principles apply to C.

Comment: Additionally, there is no possible value you can use as a "calculation failed" return value in this particular case, since any `double` you choose is also a legitimate return value for the sum of two `double`s.

Comment: @veredesmarald You can use NaN (assuming that your system uses IEEE 754 doubles, of course) as a "calculation failed" value, and if sometimes NaN is a legitimate return value you can use one NaN bit pattern as a legitimate return and another NaN bit pattern as "calculation failed."  But that's really messy.

Comment: @veredesmarald 6.2.5.20 of the C99 Standard `A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type`

Comment: `man printf` is a good idea. But I prefer a text book that is well thumbed. Guess I am getting old!

Comment: @EdHeal Lol - but at least you cannot leave the man page on the bus ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCornish - So you have my laptop!

Comment: @EdHeal Is it a i386 with an LCD screen - yeah sorry it is in my loft

Comment: @AdrianCornish - Keep the hunk of c**p - but your answer has been noted wrt to `printf`. My mates are amazed about the number of text books floating around with a variety of postit (tm) notes with different colours stuck in them (WHY OH WHY CANNOT I GET FIREFOX TO USE ENGLISH NOT THIS AMERICAN VARIATION FOR SPELL CHECKING)

Comment: @EdHeal I am a Brit living in the US - been here too long - giving up on the fact that English is a defacto standard and American English is a version ;-). Ie I do not have a British Accent - you have an American Accent - I have no accent ;-)

Comment: @pst C99 has no concept of the C++2003 or C++2011 standards so it can use the word in any context it likes - Do not apply newer definitions of a word to previous standards.

Comment: @AdrianCornish - I do have an accent - it is Somerset, but I live in Edinburgh. The BF is Scottish and the mutt is Irish. As to the previous comment is down to semantics

Comment: @EdHeal Your accent is a regional variation on pronunciation rather than a spelling thing.

Comment: No it is not = color ok colour (red things underneath), gray, center, etc. What the hell happened on that boat?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your honesty. It is refreshing.

The line should read

```
returnValue = add(2.0, 5.0, &result);
```

And to print out the result look up [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) - That will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written does not assign a value to result when the variable is declared.  Thus it contains some random number.  It is obviously bad to use this number to do anything, as it will cause your program to have unpredictable results.  This would be what is referred to as an uninitialized variable error.

Your code does not refer to the variable before it is assigned, so I am not saying you have a bug.  I am simply answering the question of what result contains before it is assigned to.  If you want it to have a particular value, you can declare it like this:

```
double result = 7;
```

and it would always have some predefined value.  Again, there is no need to do this in your case, I'm just saying you could if you wanted an always defined value.